# Evaluating predictive models

Tags: self-study, classification, predictive-models

**I am looking for ways of evaluating the performance/success of predictive (classification) models for economic purposes.**

I know of:

- Direct accuracy percentage
- AUC score
- Net profit
- Rate of return
- Sharpe ratio

**Could you inform me of other possible ways of evaluating the performance/success of such models?**

Thank you.

PS: In case it's relevant to your answer:  there's 2 possible categories the model will classify data objects in.

Answer (score 2):

There is little use in making an exhaustive list of score functions. For each application, you should define your objectives. The best score function to use will follow quite naturally from that (and is often tailored specifically to your application and its tradeoffs).

You should ask yourself questions until you know exactly what you want. Some examples:

- What is the cost of misclassification of each category?
- Does misclassifying one class cost more than misclassifying the other?
- Do you need a certain minimum correct classification rate? Does this differ per class?
- Do you want probabilities or do you only want to rank?
- ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Those are very good points.  However, my goal is not to make an exhaustive list of score functions, but rather finding other existing ones that I am not yet aware of. Then I can see whether they would fit my application or not.

Answer (score 1):

Matthews Correlation Coefficient : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient